# constantly reading data from database using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a constantly updated database (5s Interval value) and my intention is to read the new data that has been updated in the database, below is my first draft code. However, I managed to read it until the last line at the time the code is executed and then it stop. I need the code to constantly run so that it fetch the new data entry (our database is updated every 5 second).

```
import csv
import pyodbc

server = '*****' 
database = '******' 
username = '******' 
password = '*****' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from marketc")

row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print (row)
```

*it maybe hard to understand, but the main point is i just want to read the last row in our database in which the database is constantly updated for every 5 second.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is define what "the last row" is. Your SELECT statement has no ORDER BY clause so the results are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to code it. I just import the time package then looping it and check the database again for every 6 second since I know a new values will be updated in database for every 5 second.

```
import csv
import pyodbc
import time

server = '*****' 
database = '******' 
username = '******' 
password = '*****' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from marketc")

while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print (row)
        time.sleep(6)
```

Comment: Nope - eventually you will find out that rows in a table have no particular order. You might think otherwise based on your current environment - which is probably very lightly loaded with little contention for resources. And your code simply sleeps 6 seconds between fetching the rows one by one - so expecting this to fetch/display the "last" row makes little sense.